Is it possible to change the AirDrop location on my Mac without downloading random stuff from the internet?
I dislike the Downloads folder. I don't use it, and whenever something goes there it's lost forever because I never remember that folder exists and so never remember to look in there. I use Desktop for everything: screenshots, browser downloads, folders full of random stuff I've yet to put in the correct section of my personal folder, etc. I'd like AirDrop to behave that way as well.
I couldn't find anything in System Settings to change the AirDrop location. I found this, but the very first step is to download some script from GitHub, and to be quite honest I stopped reading after that; I hate sites that require me to download random stuff in order to get my Mac to work the way I want it to.
Is there any way to make AirDrop files I receive go directly to Desktop?

What version of macOS do you need this to work? Great research on that script. It looks very legitimate from the words, but you are correct - you need to spend time inspecting it to ensure the download matches the documentation - always.

So make an alias to the downloads folder to keep on the desktop.

The only thing I hate more than downloading random stuff in order to get my Mac to work the way I want it to is when the only way to accomplish it is to pay for some app that implements something the OS should have covered... or worse yet, when it can't actually be done!

If you're worried about downloading the script, you could just recreate it yourself. It's only 25 lines, so would be pretty easy to do so.

Are you able to simply sort the Downloads folder by date added so that whatever you need is always accessible and you can then move it to whatever final destination you choose? If you move everything to Desktop instead of Downloads you've just moved the problem.

@bmike Running macOS 14 at the moment.

@SolarMike Not a solution to my problem, but thanks for your input, I suppose.

@Elezar Is the script safe, though? I'm not proficient in AppleScript.

@Ezekiel Not ideal for the same reason Solar Mike's comment doesn't work for me. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve extra clicks/drags. If things are in Desktop, I know where they are and can later move them where I need them to; if some are in Desktop and some are in Downloads, it's extra hassle.

That solution seems unnecessarily complicated if all you want to do is move airdropped items to the Desktop. You can create your own Automator action to do this and attach it to the Downloads folder as a Folder Action, without having to download somebody else's script or application.
See Automatic moving of documents using Automator (Apple Discussions).

Maybe I wasn't clear enough when asking my question. I don't want an easy way to move things from Downloads to Desktop (I can just open Downloads and drag everything to Desktop manually). I'm looking for a way to make things I receive via AirDrop go directly to Desktop. Then I don't have to periodically open Downloads and move everything from one place to the other.

There is no way to do that, as far as I know. But the suggested solution is functionally the same. Anything added to the Downloads folder will be moved automatically and immediately to the Desktop. You won’t have to open the folder.

Doesn't the suggested solution require me to click something (i.e. to run the script)?

No. The script is triggered when anything is added to the folder. That’s what “Folder Action” means.

For the recent macOS releases, there is no setting to change this. The article you listed uses Finder folder actions and official scripting hooks that Apple intends for this sort of automation.

Automator User Guide for macOS Sonoma

You should be able to type in the instructions from the excellent article you posted instead of downloading. Either way, you’ll want to review each line and typing is probably better for you and not a huge effort for anyone new to scripting. This is an ideal first project, so please give it a shot.
If your time is limited, you could spend money instead of time with a commercial product: Hazel is amazing and has great documentation, functionality, performance and support.

+1 for the middle paragraph: downloading or following a script is very different from downloading an app.  An app is essentially opaque: you have no idea what it’s doing.  A script is basically just a more efficient way of running a list of commands, which you could instead just type out by hand if you prefer.  So with a script, you can get the same effect without relying on the download, and you can scrutinise what it’s doing as much as you want.

Thanks. I guess I'll give it a go when I have some free time. I'm just always wary of any script that messes with system settings, since I don't know AppleScript and I can't immediately tell whether or not it's safe. (It's less about downloading stuff from the internet and more about not knowing what the script does, so typing it out myself, as has been suggested multiple times, doesn't really help). But you're right, better a script I can read and at least try to understand than an app which works as a black box.

You can't set up AirDrop to send files directly to your desktop in macOS. By default, they always go to the Downloads folder. You will need to manually move them from your downloads to your desktop after you get them.

The last sentence is an incorrect conclusion. Even though you can't change the folder that AirDrop writes to, you can use a script or Automator to automatically move the files as they arrive, instead of manually doing so. As the other answers that were written before this one have shown.
